# Is there a way to specify that a certain app always stay in memory?

Tags: macos, reminders

I notice sometimes when I open the Reminders app (after not having opened it for a while), it takes a second to load. This is presumably because it is no longer in memory and loading from SSD. Is there a way I can tell OS X to never remove Reminders from memory?

P.S. I minimize Reminders, not close it. Which is why it sometimes stays in memory.

Comment: It takes a while because you probably haven't accessed the hard drive in a while and it has since gone to sleep, which then takes a second to wake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set the application priority (to remain in the RAM).

Your system automatically manages the resources based on current usage.

However, depending on your Reminders settings, and what external (Internet) accounts you use, it might take a moment for it to check those accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it seems unlikely that networking is related to the "issue" I'm seeing. Unless the app simply doesn't show itself at all until it has done its networking checks.